# Incorporating jquery UI progress bar for long running PHP process

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm working on a chat log manager - I wanted more control over Thunderbird's chat log archives. There's a synch functionality that basically parses the log files and uploads the messages to a database, zips the logs and stores them in an archive folder.

This process takes a long time to run, and I'd like to display a progress bar. I'm using both jQueryUI and Bootstrap - so a solution that would utilize either of these would be acceptable.

I've tried implementing both of these to no avail so far. The progress bar doesn't show up, and there's no way for me to tell if it's being incremented or not.

I've pasted the code I've got so far. Any help would be appreciated... I have basic knowledge of CSS and my knowledge of javascript is limited at best.

HTML Head

```
<script>
    function UpdatePBar(x){
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "value", x );}
</script>
```

HTML Body

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Synch process PHP

```
if(count($this->Contacts) > 0)
        {
            //GET CONTACTS ALIASES
            $result = $this->GetContacts_aliases($folderPath);
            if($result) {
                echo '<script>UpdatePBar(10)</script>';
                flush();
                //SYNCH CONTACTS
                $result = $this->synch_Contacts();
                echo '<script>UpdatePBar(20)</script>';
                flush();
                if ($result) {
                    //SYNCH MESSAGES
                    $result = $this->synch_Messages($folderPath);
                    echo '<script>UpdatePBar(50)</script>';
                    flush();
                    if ($result) {
                        //SYNCHING SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED
                        $log = "Synching of Messages Complete without errors. <br><br>";
                        $this->log = $this->log . $log;

                        //UPDATE LAST SYNCHED
                        $result = $this->UpdateLastSynched();
                        echo '<script>UpdatePBar(70)</script>';
                        flush();
                        if (!$result) {
                            //Update lastSynched failed
                            $log = "Updating lastSynched failed! <br><br>";
                            $this->log .= $log;
                        } else {
                            $log = "Updated Last Synched date stamp without errors <br><br>";
                            $this->log .= $log;

                            //ARCHIVE LOGS
                            $result = $this->ArchiveLogs($folderPath);
                            echo '<script>UpdatePBar(100)</script>';
                            flush();
                            if ($result) {
                                $log = "Archiving of log files successful!<br><br>";
                                $this->log .= $log;
                            } else {
                                $log = "Archiving of log files unsuccessful.<br><br>";
                                $this->log .= $log;
                            }

                        }
                    } else { 
...
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: When you say "to no avail," what does that mean more specifically? Does the progress bar not show up at all? Does it not update properly? I think a more detailed description of the problem would be helpful for a potential answerer.

Comment: I will update the question with more detail, but the result is that the bar doesn't show up... there's no way for me of telling if it's getting incremented or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do that trough recursive ajax calls.

create a file on php that returns the percentage;

```
Example: getPercentage.php 
<?
//do your stuff

echo $PERCENTAGE;
?>

Then on jquery:

<script>
readPHP();

function readPHP () {
   var file="getPercentage.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: file,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data , status ) {
         percentage=data;
         if (percentage < 100)
         {
           $("#progressbar").progressbar({
               value:percentage
           })
           setTimeout(readPHP(),1000);
         }
         else
         {
           $("#progressbar").progressbar({
               value:percentage
           })

         }
        }
   })
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to incorporate this as my processes are within a class. I created an object called Synch, in which there is the function launching the processes. It's from this function my bit of code was pasted.

Comment: I understand. My solution would be for more flexible code. On your function, on the places you do the <script>UpdatePBar(xx) </script>, if you could replace for updates to a record on database or even updates on a text file, so you can read this on the getPercentage.php.